# TDF transmitter to arduino

Tags: arduino, rf, clock, pll

1) I have a project to build a time clock based on the TDF signal on 162kHz, from Allouis, France. The time coding is similar to DCF-77 so I will send it to an Arduino with proper code. I managed to build an antenna and i can get the phase modulated signal but I don't know how to demodulate it ? 
Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDF_time_signal

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: yes, using a CD 4046 you get a signal which you pass on a rising edge detector